# Applying plane detection to multiple scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Before explaining the problem, I will explain the need. Imagine an AR experience that plays out like a story. There's different scenes with their own voice overs, and I've created buttons that click through them so that users can move through them at their own pace.

I have been using Unity's AR core setup and AR foundation to make this happen, but I've been struggling with applying plane detection based on the need of the above mentioned setup. I am in a rather frustrating position of having to scour for the right resources. For one thing, tutorials either focus exclusively on applying plane detection and making that the main feature (when my need is that it just needs to function as the anchoring point for the different scenes, the plane doesn't need to be visible and rendered as a mesh) or that the plane detection has something on it, but it's a "place object on tap" functionality that duplicates objects instead of just becoming the anchoring point of a single object.

If anyone has any suggestions or can point me to a helpful resource, it would be greatly appreciated. I would also be happy to provide the links to these tutorials if deemed necessary.

Comment: AR Plane or Plane detection does not work well, they will constantly change positions when pixels are lost, however, with good light in the room, it can work tolerably. I would advise you not to use AR Plane, instead just add an object to AR Session and change the Y position by about -1 or more.

Comment: Not quite sure how this would help me anchor my objects but I'm about to try it anyway, I'll let you know how it goes.